# Restart after IndexOutOfBoundsException Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an IndexOutOfBoundsException and when this happens i want to restart my program or jump back into my while loop.
Is this possible?

Comment: The reason this is downvoted is because this question doesn't show research or any effort.The relevant code is also absent. Since the question is too generic it is not a specific question, which is what we expect here on stackoverflow. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your loop in a loop and a try/catch block:

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    try {
        doStuff();
        done = true;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }
}
```

In this code, `doStuff()` is your loop. You'll probably also want to do some additional bookkeeping so you don't just repeat the exception forever.

Comment: This will effectively ignore the exception and continue in the while loop.  However, exceptions should not be ignored, and rather fixed if possible.

Comment: @Vulcan - That's a general rule that applies when there is no context, but OP may have a reason for wanting to just try again. Perhaps the loop (now an inner loop) is interacting with another thread, or with the user. Depending on the logic of the program, a particular exception may or may not need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, but in general you use the `catch` statement to continue with your program flow.

If you want to restart the program, wrap its execution in a startup script that restarts your program if it exits with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try and catch blocks :

```
while (condition) {
try {

 // your code that is causing the exception

  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    // specify the action that you want to be triggered when the exception happens
   continue; // skipps to the next iteration of your while 

 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is hard to see exactly what needs to be done to jump back into your while loop. But:

When the IndexOutOfBoundsException happens, you can catch it and do what you need, eg:

```
public static void actualprogram() {
  // whatever here
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  boolean incomplete = true;
  while (incomplete) {
    try {
      actualprogram();
      incomplete = false;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      // this will cause the while loop to run again, ie. restart the program
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not use a catch statement. You are considering the indexOutOfBoundsException as part of your normal program flow.

There are certain situations in which this error can occur. It might be a set of fields that is not filled in completely for example. My solution would be to test for that situation that causes your exception and act appropriately.

```
if (fieldsNotCompleted()){
    restart(); // or continue; or ...
} else {
    while ( ... ) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

This way, you make your program more readable and easier to fix. You also act according to the situation, and not to some magical error that turned up of which you are not certain about the cause. Error catching shouldn't be part of normal program flow.